# Determine if the following sequence (recursive formula) is bounded and monotonic

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came across this problem:

$  x_{n+1}= x_n^2 -2x_n +2 $

where

$  1<x_0<2$,  $n ∈ N_0$

Determine if this sequence is bounded and monotonic.

I'm having problems with both parts of the question:

When it comes to testing if it is monotonic, I get that

$x_{n+1} -x_n >0$ (assumption it is increasing)

Afterwards, substituting $x_{n+1}$ I get that $(x_n -2)(x_n-1)>0$ so the solution is $   x_n ∈(-∞,1)⋃ (2,∞)$

But if I put $n=0$, the solution is invalid as in the problem description we have that

$  1<x_0<2$

Does that mean that this sequence is **decreasing**? And how should I proceed to test for whether or not is it bounded? I mean, I can start with mathematical induction because we have that $n_0 <2, n_0 >1$, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Thanks!!

Comment: Things become easier to see if you look at $y_n = x_n - 1$.

Comment: $x_n -1$ or $ x_{n-1} $? Sorry, I'm kinda confused.

Comment: The first. It's clear that then $(y_n)$ is monotonic or bounded if and only if $(x_n)$ is. But it's easier to see for $(y_n)$.

Comment: You draw a correct conclusion, I'd say. Also note that $x_{n+1}=(x_n-1)^2+1>0$...

Comment: The solution of you inequation in the middle, is not correct.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah Inequation in the middle? Is not correct? I mean, thanks for your help, but much more clarification and elaboration on your part is necessary.

Comment: I just applied the classical  method used to study recursive sequences given by $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^2-2x+2$.

then
$$x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$$ with
$$f'(x)=2(x-1).$$

The fixed points of $ f $ are $1$ and $2$.
$\Bigl( \; f(1)=1 \;\;, \;f(2)=2 \; \Bigr)$

$ f$ is increasing at $[1,2]$ and $f([1,2])=[1,2]$.

the sequence is well defined and
$$(\forall n\in \Bbb N_0 ) \;\; x_n\in [1,2]$$

thus the sequence is bounded.

On the other hand,

for $x\in[1,2],$

$f(x)-x=(x-1)(x-2)\le 0$

thus
$f(x_n)\le x_n$ or $x_{n+1}\le x_n$.

the sequence is decreasing and it will converge to $1$.

Take for example $ x_0 =1.9, $ compute $x_1, x_2, x_3$ and see what happens.